# Transition probability of markov chain

Tags: markov-chains, transition-matrix

I want to find transition probabilities of a Markov chain. However, one step probability of state transition is not a fixed but is dependent on the number of users with specific state.
Below is detail:

There are total N users. Each user have a state in a unit time. The state diagram is attached  (state diagram.jpeg).
[image: state diagram.jpeg]

However the state transition probability PS  is not a fixed value, but dependent on the number of users with state Ot and Bt.
Therefore, I cannot write one step transition probability as 
$$
P =
\begin{pmatrix} 1-Po& 0&Po& 0\\
    0& 1-Pr& 0& Pr\\
    Ps& 1-Ps& 0& 0\\
    Ps& 1-Ps& 0& 0
\end{pmatrix}, $$where $O, B, Ot, Bt$ states are corresponded to $1, 2, 3, 4$.

Is there any idea to find a transition probability matrix?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If all of the users are identical, then your state space consists of vectors that count how many users are in each state, giving $\binom{N+3}3$ states.

Comment: I want to solve mathematically. But, counting is just like simulation

Comment: Think again. There’s a world of difference between defining the correct state space and what it is that you need to keep track of to model the system and simulating the system.